# What does val mean in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

When seeing documentation of modules in Ocamel there is something like this for example in Graphics Module

```
val close_graph : unit -> unit
```

Or when writing a function in an interactive mode:

```
# let x () = 3;; 
val x : unit -> int = <fun>
```

there is `val x : unit -> int = <fun>`, What is `val` and it's use case?

Comment: I always assumed that val was the type signature for that symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `val` is a keyword in OCaml with several different uses.

The cases you mention are both, in essence, that `val` is used in a module signature to specify values that appear in the module. Values are things like functions and expressions. (An example of something that's not a value that can appear in a module is a type.)

You can read about module signatures in [the OCaml manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/5.0/htmlman/modtypes.html).

The first variant of the nonterminal *specification* is the one that begins with `val`.

(In the toplevel, you are creating a module as you type in your definitions. So the toplevel is using signature-style syntax to show what you've defined. So it seems to me anyway.)

Comment: the code I'm looking at has a module defined as `module Proof = (val p)` which seems to be yet another usecase for that keyword. BTW your link is dead. This links explains the two usages: https://cs3110.github.io/textbook/chapters/modules/modules.html#first-class-modules

Comment: Yes, `val` is used io unpack a module when treated as a value (first class module).